# Use JMS 2.0 to use delivery delay with IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using IBM MQ with Spring Boot and I'm trying to delay messages with the setDeliveryDelay(time) method.
This function is only supported in JMS 2.0 and I'm having problems with this, as I am running with JMS 1.1 and I cannot figure out how to upgrade to 2.0

I'm using this dependency

`implementation(group: 'com.ibm.mq', name: 'mq-jms-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.6.2')`

and creating this bean:

```
@Bean("mqTemplate")
public JmsTemplate jmsClient(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
    System.out.println(connectionFactory.createConnection().getMetaData().toString());
    JmsTemplate temp = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    return temp;
}
```

Then I simply set the delay and send the message:

```
jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(101010);
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);
```

At startup I can see this:

```
|   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionMetaDataImpl@71f29d91  :-  
|   |   XMSC_JMS_MAJOR_VERSION     :-  1
|   |   XMSC_JMS_MINOR_VERSION     :-  1
|   |   XMSC_JMS_VERSION           :-  1.1
|   |   XMSC_MAJOR_VERSION         :-  6
|   |   XMSC_MINOR_VERSION         :-  0
|   |   XMSC_OBJECT_IDENTITY       :-  1911725457
|   |   XMSC_PROVIDER_NAME         :-  IBM MQ
|   |   XMSC_VERSION               :-  6.0
|   |   XMSC_WMQ_COMMAND_LEVEL     :-  910
|   |   XMSC_WMQ_PROVIDER_VERSION  :-  6.0.0.0
```

And as you can see the `XMSC_JMS_VERSION` is `1.1` and when I try to send to the queue I get the following error:

`JMSCC5008: Use of the JMS2.0 Function 'Delayed Delivery' is not supported with this instance of this connection`

This makes sense since I'm not using JMS 2.0, but can I change the JMS version from 1.1 to 2.0?

Comment: Which JMS API jar do have in your classpath? I use for example `javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar` together with `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.4.jar`.

Comment: I have `javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar` together with `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar`. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Are you also using connection pooling? I remember seeing a post somewhere that the pooled-jms option was incompatible with JMS2. Though spring's CachingConnectionFactory is ok.

Comment: @MarkTaylor No, I'm not using connection pooling. I tried using CachingConnectionFactory but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: There's no explicit "create a JMS2 connection" option. It's done based on the methods you call.

createConnection is a JMS1 method; createContext is the JMS2 equivalent.

It all seems to work fine if I let Spring do the creation for me

Comment: @MarkTaylor I tried this and I get this error instead: `JMSCC5007: Use of the JMS2.0 API 'createContext()' is not supported with this instance of this connection
Only connections with a correct type of connection can support using the JMS2.0 API`

When you write `Let Spring do the creation for me`, Is that not the way I've implemented the code by creating a bean?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other jms API jars being picked up first in your class path?

Comment: @JoshMc Are you sure that the JMS API jars can do this?  I'm running some tests myself, and I'm puzzled as to why the provider version is 6.0 and the JMS version is 1.1.

Comment: @JoshMc et.al   My factory has: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionMetaDataImpl@76510f6d  :
 XMSC_IS_Z_SERIES           :-  false
 XMSC_JMS_MAJOR_VERSION     :-  2
 XMSC_JMS_MINOR_VERSION     :-  0
 XMSC_JMS_VERSION           :-  2.0
 XMSC_MAJOR_VERSION         :-  8
 XMSC_MINOR_VERSION         :-  0
 XMSC_OBJECT_IDENTITY       :-  1985023853
 XMSC_PROVIDER_NAME         :-  IBM MQ JMS Provider
 XMSC_VERSION               :-  8.0.0.0
 XMSC_WMQ_COMMAND_LEVEL     :-  910
 XMSC_WMQ_PROVIDER_VERSION  :-  8.0.0.0

Comment: @DougGrove are you using the jms.jar that came with 8.0?

Comment: @John make sure the `SVRCONN` you connect to has a `SHARECNV` value of 1 or higher,  if it is set to 0 it treats  the queue manager you connect to a a v6 queue manger which didn't support delayed delivery.

Comment: @JoshMc I believe that your comment above is the correct solution.  Sadly, my JMS API dependencies are mess.  I hadn't looked, but I am pulling in JMS API bundles from several places.  The `com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:jar` has as a dependency `javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `SVRCONN` you connect to has a `SHARECNV` value of `1` or higher, if it is set to `0` the client will treat the queue manager being connected to as a v6 queue manager which didn't support JMS 2.0 features including delayed delivery, shared subscriptions.  It also does not support IBM MQ auto reconnect logic and bidirectional heart beat messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just continuing the conversation, but I'd like to do some formatting...

I change my maven dependency from:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This still resulted in:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionMetaDataImpl@70988f36  :-
XMSC_IS_Z_SERIES           :-  false
XMSC_JMS_MAJOR_VERSION     :-  2
XMSC_JMS_MINOR_VERSION     :-  0
XMSC_JMS_VERSION           :-  2.0
XMSC_MAJOR_VERSION         :-  8
XMSC_MINOR_VERSION         :-  0
XMSC_OBJECT_IDENTITY       :-  1889046326
XMSC_PROVIDER_NAME         :-  IBM MQ JMS Provider
XMSC_VERSION               :-  8.0.0.0
XMSC_WMQ_COMMAND_LEVEL     :-  910
XMSC_WMQ_PROVIDER_VERSION  :-  8.0.0.0
```

With text message properties:

```
JMSMessage class: jms_text
JMSType:          null
JMSDeliveryMode:  1
JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
JMSDeliveryTime:  0
JMSExpiration:    0
```

I have no idea how `XMSC_VERSION` can get set to 6.0.  I don't see an option on the client code or in anything like `mqclient.ini`.

Hopefully helpful.